# Login Program password masking enhancement in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, authentication

A few days ago, I had asked help from you guys for an advanced(kind of) login system in c++. Thanks to your support, I did get get it right, but now I am looking to add more features to the program. Currently, it is capable of taking in a username string, take in a password char string and also mask the password, and compare them both with pre-set values again and again until they match.
Now , the problem is that since I use `getchar()` to input data into the char array, even if I press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, it'll take that as an input for the array. Also, I can only enter values upto 8 characters, after which, even without pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it automatically goes to the next step.
I want the code to be modified such that it can take any number of characters as an input, mask them, and then, when the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it stops taking further values to fill up more array characters. So basically, almost like `cin` except it echoes `'*'` for every character entered.Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <conio.h>` 

using namespace std;  
int main()  
{
   int i=0;string u,p;char parr[8],ch;  
   while (1)
   { 
 system("cls");
 cout<<"Enter username."<<endl;
 cin>>u;
 system("cls");
 cout<<"Enter password."<<endl;
 for (i=0;i<=7;++i)
 {
     ch=getch();
     parr[i]=ch;
     cout<<'*';
 }

 parr[8]='\0';
 string p="password";

 if (u=="username" && parr==p)
 {
    system("cls");
    cout<<"Welcome!";
    break;
         }

 else
 {
     system("cls");
     cout<<"Username and password entered does not match! Please try again.";
 }
 getch();
   }    
     getch();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a condition to quit after Enter and expand the array to a reasonably large size:

```
char parr[30];

cout << "Enter password." << endl;

for (i = 0; i < 29; ++i)
{
    ch=getch();
    if (ch == '\r')
    {
        parr[i] == '\0';
        break;
    }
    parr[i]=ch;
        cout<<'*';
}
parr[29] = '\0';
```

Comment: Whoa! Enter is represented by '\r'? But everywhere I searched in google, it was '\n'...That's why I went wrong when I tried the same thing. Anyway, thanks for your reply. It works perfectly.

Comment: By the way, do you know any way to not take into consideration the Backspace key?